# Get number of ISO weeks in given year in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

I'm trying to get the number of **ISO week**s in given year/leap year. I saw that **.Net Core 3.0** have `ISOWeek.GetWeeksInYear` class, but we're running .Net Core **2.2.1**... and it's not possible to update at the moment...

I've tried this:

```
var cultInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var lastDayOfYear = new DateTime(2019, 12, 31);
var numberOfWeeks = cultInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                                    lastDayOfYear,
                                    cultInfo.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                                    DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

With `2019` it returns `53`, it's *not correct* by the result I wanted (`52`). And if I change the date to `2020` it is `53`, which is *correct*, but yeah, not by ISO which is what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [`IsoWeek`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ISOWeek.cs,d4f4c0de43b053b0) sources and particular [`WeeksInYear`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ISOWeek.cs,eabee4d1f7c55f7d) method, it's pretty small and straightforward, you can implement this by yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [`ISOWeek`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/ISOWeek.cs,d4f4c0de43b053b0) sources and implement this method by yourself (since you can't target .NET Core 3.x)

```cs
private const int WeeksInLongYear = 53;
private const int WeeksInShortYear = 52;

public static int GetWeeksInYear(int year)
{
    if (year < 1 || year > 9999)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(year));
    }

    static int P(int y) => (y + (y / 4) - (y / 100) + (y / 400)) % 7;

    if (P(year) == 4 || P(year - 1) == 3)
    {
        return WeeksInLongYear;
    }

    return WeeksInShortYear;
}
```

Then use it

```cs
var weeks = GetWeeksInYear(2019); //returns 52
weeks = GetWeeksInYear(2020); //returns 53
```

Please, keep in mind, that [static local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#static-local-functions) are supported starting from C# 8, so you should switch to this version or rewrite a code a little bit

Answer (score 2):

A year contains `53` [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) if and only if it contains `53` **Thursdays**; so in order to return `53` a year must either

1. Start from `Thursday`
2. Be a *leap year* and starts either from `Thursday` or `Wednesday`

**Code:**

```
public static int GetWeeksInYear(int year) {
  if (year < DateTime.MinValue.Year || year > DateTime.MaxValue.Year)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(year));

  var dw = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).DayOfWeek;

  return (dw == DayOfWeek.Thursday) || 
         (dw == DayOfWeek.Wednesday) && DateTime.IsLeapYear(year) 
    ? 53
    : 52;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(1990, 2020 - 1990 + 1)
    .Select(year => $"{year} : {GetWeeksInYear(year)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
1990 : 52
1991 : 52
1992 : 53
1993 : 52
1994 : 52
1995 : 52
1996 : 52
1997 : 52
1998 : 53
1999 : 52
2000 : 52
2001 : 52
2002 : 52
2003 : 52
2004 : 53
2005 : 52
2006 : 52
2007 : 52
2008 : 52
2009 : 53
2010 : 52
2011 : 52
2012 : 52
2013 : 52
2014 : 52
2015 : 53
2016 : 52
2017 : 52
2018 : 52
2019 : 52
2020 : 53
```